# iOS apps error logging

Tags: android, ios, hybrid

Please answer 2 questions below
1) By Default `iOS` devices have crash report generation. Is this sufficient to analyse what went wrong in a `hybrid` app installed on the device? Can we know what went wrong in all the cases like the problem was in `js file or native code` etc?

2) For error logging what mechanism do most of the hybrid apps follow? Do most of the apps use any predefined 3rd party `plugin` or they write their own custom plugin? Which is a preferable way of logging client side errors for 'hybrid' apps targeting ios and android platforms?
(considering the basic feature of apps, they can switch between online & offline mode).